# Using Cinder-OpenCV with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, cinder

I recently cloned [Cinder-OpenCV](https://github.com/cinder/Cinder-OpenCV) into my Cinder blocks directory. I am on the dev branch since that contains sample for Visual Studio 2013 instead of 2011. However, I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and when I run the Basic example I get

```
opencv_core249d.lib(system.obj) : error LNK2038: mismatch detected for '_MSC_VER': value '1800' doesn't match value '1900' in ocvBasicApp.obj
```

I know it's a linking issue but I'm new to Visual Studio and not sure how to fix the settings. Thanks for your help!

Comment: That means your using a binary for a Visual Studio 2013 instead of Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: So how do I fix that?

Comment: ***not sure how to fix the settings.*** Get the correct binaries for your compiler.

Comment: Could you please break that down for me?

Comment: I just looked at the github page. You can not use this fork with Visual Studio 2015 unless you install the Visual Studio 2013 (v120)  toolset. I am sorry for the confusion. I expected the github fork to contain source code not binaries..

Comment: I cloned Cinder-OpenCV from github. I'm not sure how to build it at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106933/discussion-between-kat-and-drescherjm).

Comment: @Kat I liked your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve the issue I downloaded Visual Studio 2013, ran Cinder using the 2013 Platform Toolset settings in the 2015 IDE, and then was able to run the OpenCV samples in the 2013 Platform Toolset settings in the 2015 IDE.